# Integrating agent_orange gem to Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to Rails, trying to integrate the [agent_orange](https://github.com/kevinelliott/agent_orange) gem into my rails app to have a web stats page reporting some information about visitors (device, browser, etc.)
I've added the gem to my Gemfile, but not sure what to do next. 
it says to create new user agent parser

```
>> ua = AgentOrange::UserAgent.new(user_agent_string)
```

Where do I create it?
I just want to be able to parse the data from request.user_agent to be used for my web stats dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

After creating new User agent Parser, you have to look into the device

```
device = ua.device
```

It will provide you the device object, Now you can get all the information about the device

```
device.type
device.name
device.version
```

Also you can check whether the device is Desktop or mobile

```
device.is_mobile?
device.is_computer?
```

For more info, Look into the documentaion here, https://github.com/kevinelliott/agent_orange

Comment: Where in my app do I create a new User agent Parser?

Comment: You can create a filter in ApplicationController which will find information for each visitor

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out! I created a method in my application controller that initiates AgentOrange parser like so:

```
def set_user_agent
    ua = AgentOrange::UserAgent.new(request.user_agent)
end
```

And then I was able to use all the methods described in the documentation.